# Follower limit reached Instagram API using PHP

Tags: php, limit, instagram, instagram-api

Im trying to get all my information from my Instagram profile.
If i got <50 followers it displays correct. My test profile has like 7 - 8 followers. My real profile has like 200 followers but the max what my code is printing is 49 when limit = 0 in my functions. When I change that limit to 25000 it prints +- 100 followers. My main question is. How do i get the correct amount of followers when the amount is > 200.

my function:

```
public function getUserFollower($id = 'self', $limit = 25000)
{
    $params = array();
    if ($limit > 0) {
        $params['count'] = $limit;
    }
    return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id . '/followed-by', true, $params);
}
```

Im Calling my Object how I'm supposed to. It works.

```
$getFollowers = $instagram->getUserFollower();
```

Then I'm counting my amount of followers:

```
echo '<b>Followers:</b> '. count($getFollowers->data).'</br>';
```

But the limit in this case (using my real profile) is : 96

do i have to use the 'pagination' from instagram? If i need to, how should i do that?

Thanks in advance,

Armando v O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now. Im doing it without the pagination class. So it's saving code. Means less server space. (Not that it's much space).

```
$getFollowers = $instagram->getUserFollower()
$iFollowers = 0;
do{
    $iFollowers += count($getFollowers->data);

    if($getFollowers->pagination->next_url){
        $getFollowers = json_decode(file_get_contents($getFollowers->pagination->next_url));
    } else {
        $getFollowers = FALSE;
    }

}while ($getFollowers !== FALSE);

echo 'Followers: '.$iFollowers. "<br / >";
```

Thanks for helping.